# What does "Ply" refer to in Excel terminology?

Tags: excel

(Excel 2010, and I assume others too.) On the Histogram dialog, there's a radio button labeled ""New Worksheet Ply". What does "Ply" mean in Excel?

The Help button for this dialog has no specific help, and searching Help returns suggestions for better search results.

Google finds instructions for this same dialog, some of which imply (no pun intended) that their authors think that "ply" is a synonym for "worksheet". I find that unsatisfying, because, if true, then why use the phrase "worksheet ply".

A real answer would be appreciated :-).

Edit: prompted by a couple of the responses: Yes, I do know what this radio button (and accompanying text edit slot) do. My question is about the terminology.

Comment: It's just a (in this case) redundant synonym for "sheet"

Answer (score 1):

They're using it the same way you would when talking about plywood. Each sheet of veneer in plywood is called a ply. It's a noun, used to mean layer, sheet, unit, etc.

Comment: Plywood... or toilet paper!